# How to add third party authentication urls to ASP.Net MVC

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identity

ASP.Net projects come with builtin support for loginprovider additions.

Eg: for facebook enabling we go App_start->Startup.Auth.cs and uncomment this line, simple!

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                appId: "",
                appSecret: "");
```

But Facebook has apis like this `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize`
and google has `"https://www.googleapis.com/"`
and another third party has this `"https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/authorize"`

but I did not see this urls in the asp.net project. How is .Net accessing these URl? what if the url keep changing? How can I add a new third party provider to my project?

Answer (score 0):

The providers for Facebook/Twitter/etc use custom libraries from the Owin project, you can see the source code for it all there. The endpoints are very unlikely to change as it would break countless websites.

The URLs are hardcoded in the libraries, for example the [Facebook library](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/Constants.cs) has this:

```
namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
{
    internal static class Constants
    {
        public const string DefaultAuthenticationType = "Facebook";

        internal const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
        internal const string TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        internal const string UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So if I am add a new url(a thrid party provider) then I need to do this in my asp.net project right? I could not find sample code for this online. i.e to integrate third party providers into the identity framework. Also why provide these 3 builtin when there could be many more providers out there?

Comment: Facebook is a specific implementation of the OAuth provider. If you want to roll your own, there is a library for that. But that's a longer question not suited for SO.